# Can't play muti jPlayer instance at the same time

Tags: javascript, jplayer

this is official example.

[jplayer demo](http://jplayer.org/latest/demo-03/)

if i need to more jplayer instance playing at the same time.

not one instace play and another pause to wait...

can anyone have any idea ?

thanks a lot

Comment: If you examine the code you see there's `$(this).jPlayer("pauseOthers");` in their `play` functions. I guess you just need to delete that one.